# gulp cannot output any file, with gulp-count showing at least 1 files passed to gulp.dest

Tags: gulp

I have a very simple gulpfile, like following:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var jade = require('gulp-jade');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var count = require('gulp-count');

gulp.task('jade', function (done) {
    gulp.src('./src/jade/pages/**/*.jade')
        .pipe(jade())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/'))
        .end(done);
});

gulp.task('js', function (done) {
    gulp.src('./src/js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(count('## js-files selected'))
        .pipe(concat('script.js'))
        .pipe(count('## js-files concat'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/js/'))
        .end(done);
});

gulp.task('sass', function (done) {
    gulp.src('./src/sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(count('## scss-files sass'))
        .pipe(concat('style.css'))
        .pipe(count('## css-files concat'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
        .end(done);
});

gulp.task('watch', ['jade', 'js', 'sass'], function () {
    gulp.watch(['./src/jade/pages/**/*.jade'],  ['jade']);
    gulp.watch(['./src/sass/**/*.scss'],  ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(['./src/js/**/*.js'], ['js']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['jade', 'js', 'sass']);
```

However, after I execute `gulp` or `gulp default`, there is nothing in my `www` directory.

As you can see, I have printed out the count of processed files with `gulp-count`, and it shows that there were at least 1 file passed to `gulp.dest`. Here is the CLI output:

```
[23:16:11] Using gulpfile ~/work/web/lab-page/gulpfile.js
[23:16:11] Starting 'jade'...
[23:16:11] Starting 'js'...
[23:16:11] Starting 'sass'...
[23:16:11] Finished 'jade' after 12 ms
[23:16:11] Finished 'js' after 6.81 ms
[23:16:11] Finished 'sass' after 4 ms
[23:16:11] Starting 'default'...
[23:16:11] Finished 'default' after 6.09 μs
[23:16:11] 1 js-files selected
[23:16:11] 1 js-files concat
[23:16:11] 2 scss-files sass
[23:16:11] 1 css-files concat
```

But why no files was produced ?

---

I'm using `end` function for my streams to trigger the end callback, but it seems I'm doing wrong. Now I'm using `on('end', done)` to bind the callback to the `end` event, and it works for me.

The working code is following:

```
gulp.task('jade', function (done) {
    gulp.src('./src/jade/pages/**/*.jade')
        .pipe(jade())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/'))
        .on('end', done);
});

gulp.task('js', function (done) {
    gulp.src('./src/js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(count('## js-files selected'))
        .pipe(concat('script.js'))
        .pipe(count('## js-files concat'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/js/'))
        .on('end', done);
});

gulp.task('sass', function (done) {
    gulp.src('./src/sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(count('## scss-files sass'))
        .pipe(concat('style.css'))
        .pipe(count('## css-files concat'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
        .on('end', done);
});

gulp.task('watch', ['jade', 'js', 'sass'], function () {
    gulp.watch(['./src/jade/pages/**/*.jade'],  ['jade']);
    gulp.watch(['./src/sass/**/*.scss'],  ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(['./src/js/**/*.js'], ['js']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['jade', 'js', 'sass']);
```

Am I wrong? And, what does `end` method do for a gulp stream?

Comment: The "now I'm using…" makes it sound like the snippet no longer matches what you're running. If so could you update the snippet? And, have you tried getting rid of all the `end` and `done` stuff?

Comment: @henry I've pasted my working code here. And, of course I tried to get rid of all the stuff, it works.

Comment: Wait… "it works" if instead of `function(done) ... .on('end', done);});` you use `function() ... });`?